# prevent tabbing on the icon when filling some input-fields in blazor

Tags: javascript, html, css, blazor

I'm working on a project where you can insert your working hours, in which you have to insert start- & end times. But after you put in the start time and tab to go on, it does focus first on the icon, which comes from the

```
<input type="time">
```

I want that the tabbing only hits the input area, not the icon next to it.

This is the current state:

example input field:

```
                       <div class="text-section">

                            <label for="startTime"
                            class="text label without-margin">@((MarkupString)loc["StartTime"].ToString())</label>

                            <div class="property-container-three">
                                <div class="property-icon">
                                    <div class="icon solid start" tabIndex="-2">@Icons.Startzeit</div>
                                </div>

                                <input class="input-text nomargin centerInputContentVertical"
                               type="time"
                               id="startTime"
                               @ref="startTimeElement"
                               @bind-value="blazorStartTime"
                               @onblur="HandleStartTimeSet">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I already tried everything with tabindex:"-1", it just makes no difference. Also I'm just able to modify this icon due css, which goes like:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="date"], input[type="number"], input[type="search"], input[type="time"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="password"], [type="email"], select, textarea {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I do not have any more ideas or approaches...

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this when using just the HTML (copied twice to make 2 sets of inputs). Could it be the blazor code and focus.js code is not needed? `tabindex="-1"` should be sufficient without extra code I believe

Comment: @Harrison even without the focus.js, the tabindex="-1" does not work.

Comment: I can't replicate this in pure HTML

Comment: @Harrison I've found out that the icon comes from <input type="time"> and not the icon that u see before the input element. It's like a clock; after the input, it hits there while tabbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling I found, it is a known issue with Edge... see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58066242/15291770), it states that Microsoft do not plan to fix it; but the link they mention is dead.

I can only replicate this bug on Edge. And it seems MS won't solve it...

You can target it with CSS: [idea from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002686/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-small-clock-icon-that-comes-with-the-html-input)

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` {
  display: none:
}
```

Perhaps setting `display: none` will be enough and maybe adjusting padding/margin for it too?

Unfortunately, there is currently no stable CSS way to change the `tab-index`; and currently no way to change the HTML attributes.

- The current CSS equivalent for `tab-index` is [-moz-user-focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-focus) but this is **non-standard** and the documentation stresses that you **"should not use this"**.
- Similar things exist for grabbing the pseudo element with JavaScript [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element), but again this is for `computedStyles` which is back to the CSS issue again.

Maybe in future this sort of feature will be introduced and there will be a working answer for it....